# Проверка программного кода с помощью тестов на PHP

Tags: python, php, тестирование, скрипт, командная-строка

Всем привет!

Передо мной стоит задача написать программу на PHP, которая будет открывать какой-нибудь скрипт на Python, передавать в него входные данные и сверять результат с верными выходными данными, а также замерять время работы программы. Мне нужно узнать, есть ли готовые решения, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

А если нет готовых решений, то как мне реализовать передачу входных данных в скрипт и получение выходных данных?

Answer (score 0):

готовые решения мне не известны, питон и пых имеют собственные дебагеры. передача данных может быть осуществлена двумя способами: простой при манипуляции смд запроса на выполнение скрипта типа `file.php <in.txt >out.txt` где каждая строка ввода будет вводится автоматически при запросе инфы. см "перенаправление потоков ввода вывода", так же вместо файла может быть программа. второй: правильный,- организация взаимодействия между скриптами при помощи pipe.open etc